# How can I random 0 or 1 and replace values in Python array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For my coding:

```
In[1]:
TC = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 0, 0, 0], 
      [0, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
a = np.array(TC)
arr = a.reshape(2,12) 
arr

Out[1]:
array([[   0,    0,    0,    0,    0, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000,    0,    0,
           0],
       [   0, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0]])

In[2]:
array_new=[]
for i in range (2):
    for j in range (12):
        rand=np.random.choice([0,1])
        y = np.select([arr[i][j] > 0], [rand], 999)
        array_new.append(y)
    j=j+1
i=i+1
numpy_array = np.array(array_new)
array_new = numpy_array.reshape(2,12) 
array_new

Out[2]:
array([[999, 999, 999, 999, 999,   0,   1,   0,   1, 999, 999, 999],
       [999,   1,   1,   1,   1, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999]])
```

Does any way to make each value in each row that more than zero such as 2000 1000 in TC array to be *random values, consisting three 0 and one 1, then replace it each row?

```
Target
Out[2]:
array([[999, 999, 999, 999, 999,   *0,   *0,   *0,   *1, 999, 999, 999],  
       [999,   *1,   *0,   *0,   *0, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999]])
```

Thank You in Advance

Comment: Do you always have exactly 4 values to replace per row?

Comment: yes, each row has 4 values to be replaced by random values.

Comment: Do you want to replace these values in `arr` or in `array_new`? Please clearly specify your input and expected output. Do you also want zeros replaced by `999`?

Comment: yes, replace 0 with 999  and also replace 2000 2000 2000 2000 and 1000 1000 1000 1000 with random three 0 and one 1 in arr. In array_new, I just try but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an array:

```
arr = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 0, 0, 0], 
      [0, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

It looks like you want to randomly replace four values in each row with three 0s and one 1. To do that, you'll first need to select the four values you are going to replace:

```
gt_zero = arr > 0
eq_zero = arr == 0
```

This creates two boolean arrays of the same shape as `arr` that have `True` where the condition is true, and `False` where the condition is false

Now, since you know that each row is guaranteed to have four non-zero values, you can pre-build a `Nx4` array of replacement values. First, create an array of zeros. Then, select a random column to insert `1` into for each row. Then, replace the element in that column with `1` using [`np.put_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.put_along_axis.html)

```
replacements = np.zeros((arr.shape[0], 4))
random_column = np.random.randint(0, 4, (arr.shape[0], 1))
np.put_along_axis(replacements, random_column, 1, 1)
```

At the end of this snippet, `replacements` looks like this:

```
array([[0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

Finally, replace the elements in `arr` with `replacements`. Note that you need to flatten `replacements` to be able to set the values using boolean indexing:

```
arr[gt_zero] = replacements.flatten()
arr[eq_zero] = 999
```

Which gives you the following (example) `arr`:

```
array([[999, 999, 999, 999, 999,   0,   1,   0,   0, 999, 999, 999],
       [999,   0,   0,   0,   1, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999]])
```

Comment: I appreciate the information and advice you have shared. It works

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```
# identify values >= 1000
m = arr>=1000

# create output
new_arr = np.where(m, 0, 999)

# generate random array of size len(arr)/4 with one 1 per row
tmp = np.random.random((arr.shape[0], 4))

# assign it using the mask
new_arr[m] = (tmp == tmp.max(1)[:,None]).astype(int).ravel()
```

Example output:

```
array([[999, 999, 999, 999, 999,   0,   0,   0,   1, 999, 999, 999],
       [999,   0,   1,   0,   0, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999]])
```